# Clarification on definition for this piecewise function

Tags: fourier-series, piecewise-continuity

I am working on computing the Fourier Series for the function
$$f(x) = \ \begin{cases} 
      x,\hspace{0.5cm} -L<x<L \newline
      0, \hspace{0.5cm} x \in \{-L,L\} 
   \end{cases}
\
$$

I know how to compute the coefficients for a Fourier Series using the formulas, however this function definition does not make sense to me. It seems that when f(x) is between -L and L, it is equal to both x and 0 simultaneously. Could someone please clarify this for me?  Many thanks!

Comment: When $f(x)$ is strictly between $-L$ and $L$ it is equal to $x$. It is $0$ at the endpoints (note the set $\{-L, L\}$ only contains two elements)

Comment: Thank you so much!